# Как вывести содержимое Vector?

Tags: java

Есть вектор, в который я закидываю массивы типа int. Как вывести содержимое такого вектора?

```
Vector<int[]> arrays = new Vector<int[]>();
```

Answer (score 1):

В цикле пройтись по всем элементам массивов и вывести.

Comment: @a_gura, а, если в каждом из массивов разное кол-во элементов? Я пробовал просто вывести вектор: System.out.println(arrays);

Comment: Что вам мешаеть узнать длинну каждого из массивов?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<int[]> arrays = new Vector<int[]>();
        arrays.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
        arrays.add(new int[]{4, 5, 6});

        for (int[] array : arrays) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }
```